# How to capture multiple videos into one video (video collage) iOS

Tags: ios, video, quicktime, avcapturesession

I think the question is self-explanatory. There are tons of "video collage" apps that let you "stitch" either a bunch of videos together or both videos and images.

How do they do it? My initial theory was to have the photos/videos on a single UIView and somehow record that UIView or convert it into a video file. Does Apple provide an API for this? Is there any way to record what's going on inside a UIView?

I found this class on gitHub but I'm unsure whether or not it will be fast enough to capture video: https://github.com/wess/Glimpse

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

One way in ios or osx to play with audio or video is by using AVFoundation class framework.

https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html

You can even add animation to your videos here is a link to very nice tutorial by Abdul Azeem

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos